# How to perform JavaScript's >>> in scheme?

Tags: javascript, scheme

Scheme have only `>>` and `<<` functions. How can I do [javascript `>>>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Unsigned_right_shift) in scheme?

I need to write this function in scheme:

```
function bit_rol (num, cnt) {
  return (num << cnt) | (num >>> (32 - cnt))
}
```

this will not work because >>> is unbound symbol:

```
(define (bit-rol num cnt)
    (| (<< num cnt) (>>> num (- 32 cnt))))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one solution:

```
(define (complement x)
  (if (negative? x)
      (- (expt 2 32) (- x))
      x))

(define (>>> x n)
  (cond
    [(>= n 0) (cond
                [(= x 0) 0]
                [(> x 0) (quotient x (expt 2 n))]
                [(< x 0) (>>> (complement x) n)]
                [else    (error '>>> "strange number detected")])]
    [else (error '>>> "expected a non-negative shift")]))

(>>>  5 2) ; 1
(>>> -5 2) ; 1073741822
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you did not specify a version I expect you are using the latest full version which is R6RS. R6RS has an Exact bitwise artithmetic library [(rnrs arithmetic bitwise (6))](http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs-lib/r6rs-lib-Z-H-12.html#node_idx_1062)

Scheme does not have `>>` since it's numbers are not bound by a fixed width but `>>>` and `<<` are implemented with `bitwise-arithmetic-shift` with eiher negative or positive number of shifts. There are also specific right and left versions but they are redundant.

Scheme has `bitwise-rotate-bit-field` and I believe you are emulating it in your JavaScript since it doesn't provide rotating a instruction. Your `bit-rol` can be implemented with only one use of this:

```scm
(import (rnrs)
        (rnrs arithmetic bitwise (6)))

(define (make-bit-rot bit-width)
  (lambda (n step)    
    (bitwise-rotate-bit-field n
                              0
                              bit-width
                              (if (negative? step)
                                  (mod step bit-width)
                                  step))))

(define rot-4 (make-bit-rot 4))
(rot-4 #b0001 -1) ; ==> #b1000
(rot-4 #b1000  1) ; ==> #b0001
(rot-4 #b1000  3) ; ==> #b0100


// Seeems you are interested in 32 bit rotate
(define rot-32 (make-bit-rot 32))
```

Comment: I want this function to be portable so I need it for R5RS.

Comment: @jcubic It **is** portable for all implementations that support R6RS. If you knew the version of Scheme you can tag it. r7rs, r6rs, and r5rs are tags in SO you can use to specify a standard version. I'll just leave the answer since it might be some r6rs users that will find this answer useful.